What does "90 degrees ahead of phase" mean in inductance problems?
I've been working on this homework problem and I have determined that the induced EMF on the right coil is sin(x-90). However, I do not understand what "ahead of phase means." When I graph sin(x-90) on desmos, yes, the graph is shifted to the right, but at the same time it is also lagged in comparison to sin(x) by 90 degrees.
In this context, what does the wording mean?


Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Plotted below are three graphs of $y$ against time, $t$.

Everything the blue graph does the orange graph has done earlier in time.
In this case we can say that the blue graph lags the orange graph by $\pi/2$, or the orange graph leads the blue graph by $\pi/2$.
Similarly, the blue graph leads the green graph by $\pi/2$, or the green graph lags the blue graph by $\pi/2$.
